# How to deploy docker app using docker-compose.yml in cloud foundry

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cloud-foundry

I have a docker-compose.yml file which have environment variable and certificates. I like to deploy these in cloud foundry dev version.
I want to deploy microgateway on cloud foundry link for microgateway is below-
https://github.com/CAAPIM/Microgateway

Comment: You mentioned `docker-compose`. I am guessing you have multiple services along with your app. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes there are three types of services

Comment: Hey @rishu were you able to deploy it using docker-compose.yml ?

Answer (score 1):

In cloud native world, you instantiate the services to your foundation beforehand. You can use prebuilt services (auto-scaler) available from the market place.

If the service you want is not available, you can install a tile (e.g redis, mysql, rabbitmq), which will add services to the market place. Lot of vendors provide tiles that can be installed on PCF (check on newtork.pivotal.io for the full list).

If you have services that are outside of cloud foundry (e.g. Oracle, Mongo, or MS Sql Server), and you wish to inject them into your cloud foundry foundation, you can create do that by creating User Provide Services (cups).

Once you have a service, you have to create a service instance. Think of it as provisioning a service for you. After you have provisioned i.e. created a service instance, then you can bind it to one or more apps.

A service instance is scoped to an org and a space. All apps within a org - space, can be bound to that service instance.

You deploy your app individually, by itself, to cloud foundry (jar, war, zip). You then bind any needed services to your app (e.g db, scaling, caching etc).

Use a manifest file to do all these steps in one deployment.

PCF 2.0 is introducing PKS - Pivotal Container Service. It is implementation of Kubo within PCF. It is still not GA.

Kubo, Kubernetes, and PKS allow you to deployed your containerized applications.

I have played with MiniKube and little bit of Kubo. Still getting my hands wet on PKS.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I couldn't find any article on how to deploy CAAPIM Microgateway to cloud foundry. I will have to build a poc to deploy the micro gateway to Cloud Foundry to give you more details.